# Javascript : How to capture the moment a function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am currently trying to place some code over an existing webpage that I cant modify the code. My goal is to "capture" the moment when the function is called, to call my own code afterwards.

I can see two ways about it, but so far none of my research found anything.

Way #1 : place some sort of event listener on the function itself, as far as I can tell, those only works on DOM objects, so that wouldn't work.

Way #2 : capture the function code using functionName.ToString(), append a trigger at the end and reinsert it. My issue is that I can't figure how to redefine the function while the script is running.

This is the code I'm trying to figure when it's called. It's in a global object Tie that contains a function.

```
Tie.writeChat = function() {
    this.ctiming = baseChatUpdate;
    clearTimeout(this.chatSlow);
    this.chatSlow = setTimeout(function() {
        Tie.ctiming = 60 * 1 * 1000;
        console.log("Slow chat");
    }, 60 * 15 * 1000);
    var msg = Tie.enc(Tie.id("chatmsg").value);
    var c = Tie.id("change").innerHTML;

    if (msg != "") {
        Tie.request("write.php", "msg: " + msg + ", c: " + c);
        Tie.id("chatmsg").value = "";
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Any hints as to the scope the function is being defined and called in today? Is it global (eg `window.myFun`), private to a module, etc.

Comment: Updated with it, is this what you were wanting?

Comment: It helps, but it doesn’t quite answer the requested clarifications. Is `Tie` global/accessible as `window.Tie`? Where is `Tie.writeChat` referenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Tie` is global:

```
Tie.oldwriteChat = Tie.writeChat;
Tie.writeChat = function(){
  alert("Tie.writeChat is called");
  this.oldwriteChat();
};
```